# How to add two numbers from two activities and output to a third activity

Tags: kotlin

Trying to learn Kotlin, I set myself a task that I thought would be easy - to me it isn't!

So, I just want to input a number on activity 1, press a button to take me to activity 2 where I input another number and press another button which takes me to activity 3 which displays the sum of the numbers from activities 1 and 2.

I can move between activities via the button presses but having gone through similar problems on this forum, I cannot make any progress.

Thanks for any help.

Chris

Thanks, here is what I have so far - basically, just the intents to make the button start the next activity.  In my naivety, I thought it would be a case of, from the final activity, referring to the editText id's of the numbers, summing them and the displaying the sum.  I now know that I need to use 'put.extra', but I don't know how.  All the examples that I can find are passing text from one activity to another and displaying it, not performing a mathematical operation with it.

ACTIVITY 1

```
class Num1Activity : AppcompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_num1)


        nextNumBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val secondNum = Intent(this, Num2Activity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("num1", uno.text.toString())
            startActivity(secondNum)
        }
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY 2

```
class Num2Activity : AppcompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_num2)

        gotoAnsBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val answer = Intent(this, AnswerActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("num2", dos.text.toString())
            startActivity(answer)
        }
    }
}
```

FINAL ACTIVITY

```
class AnswerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a code snippet of what you have done so far?

Comment: where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I won't get a chance to try this out until tomorrow, but I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a number in the intent you pass to the next activity and then retrieve the number in the next activity.

for example put a number in the intent using something like this:

```
intent.putExtra("num1", uno.text.toString().toInt())
```

then in the next activity you need to extract the number from the intent using 
`getIntent()`  which in Kotlin is translated to just `intent`

So in your next activity you would have something like this:

note: the intent can be null hence the use of ?

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val startIntent = intent
    println(startIntent?.getIntExtra("number", 0))
}
```

BTW, I would put the code you have in onResume() methods not the onCreate() methods.

Comment: It works! Thanks again for your help.  Using .toInt and getIntExtra were key bits of knowledge that I didn't have.

Comment: You should except the answer if it answers your question.